# Binomial distribution sum inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

I really need to know the tight bounds of following series.

Suppose $$r>l \\ q<1$$ Is there any tight bound base on $l$ parameter?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{l}{r \choose i}  q^{i}{(1-q)}^{r-i}$$

Comment: Have you looked at the standard tail bounds? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds

Comment: Didn't you ask this question yesterday already?